# Convert PHP multidimensional array so that the values become keys, and and other values become arrays for each key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, array-unique

I have:

```
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12345],
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12346],
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12347],
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12348],
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12349],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12345],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12346],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12347],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12348],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12349],
];
```

But I want:

```
    '11' => ['12345, 12346, 12347, 12348, 12349'], '12' => ['12345, 12346, 12347, 12348, 12349']
];
```

I've tried:

```
$countries = array_column($data, 'countryCode');
$countries = array_unique($countries);
$countries = array_fill_keys($countries, []);

function makeArrays(&$countries, $data){
    foreach ($countries as $countryId => $postalCodes){
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            if ($item['countryCode'] == $countryId) {
                array_push($postalCodes, $item['postalCode']);
            }
        }
    }
    return $countries;
}

makeArrays($countries, $data);
```

When I var_dump the makeArrays function though, the country ID keys are not populated with an array of postal codes like I would expect:

```
array(2) {
  [11]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [12]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

How do I get each key's array to populate with the expected values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the array and set the values as keys.

```
    $arr = [
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12345],
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12346],
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12347],
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12348],
    ['countryCode' => 11, 'postalCode' => 12349],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12345],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12346],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12347],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12348],
    ['countryCode' => 12, 'postalCode' => 12349],
]; 

//
$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $newArr[$val['countryCode']][] = $val['postalCode'];
}
print_r($newArr);
```